# Retrieve project id from Google Compute Engine machine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two Google Cloud Platform projects (staging and production). I would like my application deployed on Google Compute Engine instance to automatically detected the project id. What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can query the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata) programmatically for a variety of information, including the project id.

For the project id:

```
$ curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

This will return your project id, eg: `my-gcp-project`

Or if you need the numeric project id:

```
$ curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/numeric-project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

This will return the numeric project id, eg: `0123456789`

Answer (score 2):

You can determine project ID directly in shell script with:

```
PROJECTID=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

Or use metadata lib for your language to get required data.
I'm able to get project ID in Golang with:

```
import "cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata"
...
var ProjectId, _ = metadata.ProjectID()
```

Comment: @I.Tyger when deployed to GCP - yes, for sure. Don't remember if it did work locally. Most liky, it didn't.

Comment: It didnt work locally.  I might need the approach that works locally too for local test .

Answer (score 0):

In my environment I've got:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: metadata.google.internal
```

The following worked for me:

```
PROJECTID=`gcloud projects list | awk 'FNR>1 {print$1}'`
```

which returns the project details, which is then parsed for project id.

Comment: metadata.google.internal is not accessible outside of google cloud. Question's context is an app that's already running inside google cloud.