# How can I get current projectId inside Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The question is simple. I need projectId in order to establish connection insde Google Cloud Function. I found the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.50.0/google-cloud?method=gcloud) where it said, that projectId is optional parameter and will be checked from GCLOUD_PROJECT, but on deployed function it didn't work.

So it is the question now how can I get the projectId env variable in order to pass it as argument for Datastore connection instance, or what should be done to not pass this id and establish connection with datastore inside Google Cloud Function?

**Update 1**

I found that I actually can get variable from process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT, just like any other env.variable.
But, know is the last question, is it actually possible to use @google-cloud/datastore without any configuration object?

Comment: According to docs (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) `GCLOUD_PROJECT` is legacy and you should probably use `process.env. GCP_PROJECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in update 1 we can get all the information about environment from the ***process.env*** variable.

And the second question about configuration object for **@google-cloud/datastore**, it actually can work without any options. It will trying to fetch all required parameters from environment variables. So, it didn't work beacuase of error in my code.

Answer (score 5):

You can get project ID as `const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT`.
But for some reason the environmet variable "GCP_PROJECT" is not set when running the emulator. Instead the deprecated variable name "GCLOUD_PROJECT" is the one to select. So you might try them both.

```
const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work on newer environments, according to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#newer_runtimes

Comment: For newer environments you can query the internal metadata answered here: [questions/30887500/retrieve-project-id-from-google-compute-engine-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887500/retrieve-project-id-from-google-compute-engine-machine)

Comment: Current docs say `GCP_PROJECT` is the current env var, and that `GCLOUD_PROJECT` is deprecated. Not sure if you try now, whether the emulator will work with GCP_PROJECT. Perhaps it was running an older version of the library.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on which runtime you are using.
If your using  Python 3.7 and Go 1.11 you are in luck. Use

```
process.env.GCP_PROJECT
```

If using any of the [new runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#newer_runtimes), bad luck, either access the metadata server, or google [suggests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20If%20your%20function%20requires%20one%20of%20the%20environment%20variables%20from%20an%20older%20runtime%2C%20you%20can%20set%20the%20variable%20when%20deploying%20your%20function.%20For%20example%3A)

> Note: If your function/app requires one of the environment variables from
> an older runtime, you can set the variable when deploying your
> function. For example:

```
gcloud functions deploy envVarMemory \
--runtime nodejs10 \
--set-env-vars FUNCTION_MEMORY_MB=2Gi \
--memory 2Gi \
--trigger-http
```

If using terraform:

```hcl
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "my-function" {
  name        = "my-function"
  runtime     = "nodejs16"
  environment_variables = {
    GCP_PROJECT = var.project_id
  }
  #...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Under Cloud Functions v2 public preview (Oct 2022), there's a section called [built-in parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/config-env) that allows `require` of Project ID, Database URL and Storage bucket.

Presumably also Location ID ("Default GCP resource location") would be listed here, though that's not in the current documentation.

I did not get that to work.

However, this does:

```
const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse( process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG );

const locationId_maybe = firebaseConfig.locationId || null;
const projectId = firebaseConfig.projectId;
const databaseURL = firebaseConfig.databaseURL;
```

The env.var. is always defined. `locationId` is defined only if there's an active Firebase project. This makes sense, since it needs access to the GCP project in the cloud.

Firebase CLI 11.15.0

Answer (score 1):

For the Python 3.9 and newer runtimes you can use:

```py
from google.auth import default

_, project_id = default()
```

This requires `google-cloud-core` to be installed. It works either by using the Metadata Service or from loading service account credentials.

Answer (score 0):

if it's an HTTP function, we can use the URL to figure out the current project and region with `req.header('host')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase, the `firebase-admin` package can be used to retrieve the `projectId` by using the following:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const projectId = admin.apps[0].options.credential.projectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// package.json
{
   ...
   "firebase-admin": "^11.11.0",
}
```

Get `projectId`

```
const options = getApp().options;
const projectId = options.projectId || (options.credential as any).projectId;
```

Answer (score -1):

For any runtimes after node 8 you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcp-metadata

```
const gcpMetadata = require('gcp-metadata');

export const getGCPProjectIdFromMetadata = async () => {
    const isAvailable = await gcpMetadata.isAvailable();

    if (!isAvailable) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return gcpMetadata.project('project-id');
};
```

This will also work across any other instances you wish to launch (such as app engine).

Answer (score -2):

*When* having deployed with `firebase deploy` there's:

```
functions.config().firebase.projectId
functions.config().firebase.databaseURL
functions.config().firebase.storageBucket
functions.config().firebase.locationId
```

Comment: I just tried this and these variables aren't automatically set with just a `firebase deploy`. Do you actually need to manually set these variables for the Firebase Functions environment?

Comment: It depends on file `.runtimeconfig.json` inside the deployment, then these variables are known. Will not delete this answer, because it is correct; despite some people seem to fail with the basics already. One can browse the deployed files on the GCP console, below "sources".